# Why are my tests slow after upgrading rails from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed these upgrade instructions: http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2

Here are my three small upgrade changes:

**(1) Gemfile**

```
-gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
+gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

-gem 'rack', '1.3.3'
+#gem 'rack', '1.3.3'

 group :assets do
-  gem 'sass-rails', '  ~> 3.1.0'
-  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
-  gem 'uglifier'
+  gem 'sass-rails', '  ~> 3.2.3'
+  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
+  gem 'uglifier', '     >=1.0.3'
   gem 'asset_sync'
 end
```

**(2) config/environments/development.rb**

```
+  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
+  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

**(3) config/environments/test.rb**

```
-  config.assets.allow_debugging = true
+  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

Prior to the upgrade, my tests looked as follows (well under a second each):

```
...
StockroomTest:
     PASS stockroom must have a name (0.03s) 
     PASS stockroom name must be unique (0.01s) 
     PASS stockroom with name is valid (0.00s) 
...
Finished in 1.604118 seconds.
29 tests, 90 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
...
StockroomsControllerTest:
     PASS should create stockroom (0.04s)
     PASS should destroy stockroom (0.02s)
     PASS should get edit (0.14s)
     PASS should get index (0.11s)
     PASS should get new (0.03s)
     PASS should not destroy stockroom (0.04s)
     PASS should show stockroom (0.13s)
     PASS should update stockroom (0.02s)
...
Finished in 12.572911 seconds.
115 tests, 166 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
...
MiscellaneousTest:
     PASS get campaigns#index should redirect to newsletters#index (1.83s)
     PASS get /campaigns should redirect to / when logged out (0.06s)
Finished in 1.793070 seconds.
2 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

After (each test takes over 1 second):

```
StockroomTest:
     PASS stockroom must have a name (1.29s)
     PASS stockroom name must be unique (1.30s)
     PASS stockroom with name is valid (1.27s)
...
Finished in 41.135808 seconds.
29 tests, 90 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
...
StockroomsControllerTest:
     PASS should create stockroom (1.30s)
     PASS should destroy stockroom (1.29s)
     PASS should get edit (1.33s)
     PASS should get index (1.43s)
     PASS should get new (1.41s)
     PASS should not destroy stockroom (1.31s)
     PASS should show stockroom (1.36s)
     PASS should update stockroom (1.31s)
...
Finished in 161.803235 seconds.
115 tests, 166 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
...
MiscellaneousTest:
     PASS get /campaigns should redirect to /newsletters when logged in (5.27s)
     PASS get /campaigns should redirect to / when logged out (1.67s)
Finished in 7.034593 seconds.
2 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The following is an example of one of the unit tests from above. It takes about 1.3s to run now (after the upgrade), compared to less than 0.01s before.

**test/unit/stockroom_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StockroomTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :stockrooms

  test "stockroom with name is valid" do
    assert stockrooms(:wine_cellar).valid?, 'tried new wine_cellar'
  end
```

I know that fixtures are frowned on, and I do intend to seriously look into factories, but for the time being this is my predicament. Here is the relevant fixture:

**test/fixtures/stockrooms.yml**

```
wine_cellar:
  id: 1
  name: wine cellar
```

The only two validations on `Stockroom` are `presence` and `uniqueness`.

Note: I am running another rails app on the same machine, though it is running rails `3.2.5`, and a nearly identical unit test (the same assertion on the same two validations) finishes in 0.465489 seconds (less than half a second).

Here is what the relevant part of the test log looks like for the above "stockroom with name is valid" test:

```
 (0.9ms)  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (84.8ms)  BEGIN
 (82.3ms)  BEGIN
 (83.4ms)  BEGIN
 (79.2ms)  BEGIN
 (82.1ms)  BEGIN
Stockroom Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `stockrooms`.* FROM `stockrooms` WHERE `stockrooms`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Stockroom Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `stockrooms` WHERE (`stockrooms`.`name` = BINARY 'wine cellar' AND `stockrooms`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
 (90.9ms)  ROLLBACK
 (85.7ms)  ROLLBACK
 (90.7ms)  ROLLBACK
 (81.4ms)  ROLLBACK
 (85.4ms)  ROLLBACK
```

And for comparison, here's the "equivalent" test in my rails `3.2.5` app:

```
 (0.2ms)  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Email Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `emails`.* FROM `emails` WHERE `emails`.`id` = 980190962 LIMIT 1
Email Exists (2.8ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `emails` WHERE (`emails`.`email` = BINARY 'MyString' AND `emails`.`id` != 980190962) LIMIT 1
 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I'd personally try with the latest stable rails `3.2.7` before anything else

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately `3.2.7` made no difference.

Comment: Can you add one of your tests that is slower?

Comment: @John I have added one of the tests that is slower (all of them are slower, but I added one of the simplest ones).

Comment: @user664833 what is Ruby version do you use?

Answer (score 4):

The only answer that I could imagine is that your tests differ in *the way the transactions are processed*.

If everything works correctly, rails should wrap each test in a transaction and roll the transaction back. So you basically only "simulate" the writing actions and don't have to roll back the database after each test, thereby saving a lot of time.

If so, you might find your answer here:
[ActiveRecord Rollback does not work in Rails test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774742/activerecord-rollback-does-not-work-in-rails-test)

Only you might try to turn the feature explicitly on.

Edit: as your output show you are using transactions, there might be a difference in the way the rails environment loads. Please check spec_helper.rb for strange differences.

You could have a look on this post and check if there is something strange happening while your test suite boots up:
[Rails 3 - Speed up Console Loading Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736546/rails-3-osx-speed-up-console-loading-time/5071198#5071198)

Comment: Hmm.. but did something change between `3.1.0` and `3.2.0` to cause this? Note that in another app (created directly with rails `3.2.5` -- i.e. not upgraded from a lower version), on the same machine, a nearly identical test is not affected by this problem (neither is anything in whole test suite). Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure. However, if there is no transactional fixtures going on, I would expect some changed values in the testing database at some point. Do you experience that?

Comment: I think you're onto something! I have updated my question with logs showing a significant difference in terms of transactions (with multiple nested BEGIN/ROLLBACK transactions versus a single BEGIN/ROLLBACK in the equivalent test of another unaffected app).

Comment: With `self.use_transactional_fixtures = true` there is no difference in the tests whatsoever, whereas with `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` there are *no* BEGIN/ROLLBACK blocks (but there is also no speed difference).

Comment: That sounds really strange. Did you also change the database? It almost sounds like the database is not doing transactions.

Comment: I have made *no* changes to the database.

Comment: I have just created a new rails `3.1.0` app, and upgraded it to rails `3.2.0`, and it is **not** experiencing the same "slow tests" issue as the app in question. There must be some particular issue with it alone. I will continue digging.

Comment: Still have some rumor on my mind like nested transactions not using transactions at all, but that would not explain why all tests are slow. Still very strange.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, where running a completely empty spec takes around .5 seconds.  If I set `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` then the problem goes away.  We are running rails 3.2.11 we've been on that for a while. We only updated a handful of libraries, including activeadmin.  Maybe some weird monkeypatching of ActiveRecord is causing transaction rollbacks to go really slow?

Comment: In addition, we are also seeing the strange behavior that over the course of each spec, multiple transactions are being created and rolled back.

Comment: I know that the OP has probably moved on by now, but in case someone else comes along, as another clue, we've found that the problem doesn't show if we're using Guard and autotest.  We think it might be related.